# Adding a class to top object int the list of dynamically changing objects

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, object, vuejs2

I have an element that will v-for all the objects and I have the css class top-class{ } …I want to dynamically add top-class in rendered object that is to object[0] and it changes dynamically, so the old top must be removed.

any help on how to do that?

here is the code, in the element you can see the class

```
<section class="tiles">
        <article v-for="(item, key) in objects" :class="top-class (if its top object)">
                <span class="image">
                    <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" />
                    </span>
                    <a @click="method">                 
                                          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                <p>Sed nisl arcu euismod sit amet nisi lorem etiam dolor veroeros et feugiat.</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
        </article>

<script>
    export default {
       computed: {
           top-class() {



           }
       }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: What is `objects` ? is it an array or an object ?

Comment: `<article v-for="(item, index, key) in objects" :class="{ 'top-class': index === 0 }">` that's it, isn't it? If that was helpful then let me know, will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Dynamic Class

I'll assume you really do need a computed, and that it will return various class names.  (It's quite possible you don't.)

- Let's call it `topClass`, without the dash, it's easier.
- It's unclear whether `objects` is an array of objects or an object hash of objects, so I'll give both answers.  If `objects` is:

**Array**

```
<article v-for="(item, index) in objects" :class="{ [topClass]: index === 0 }">
```

**Object** (using 3rd `v-for` argument `index`)

```
<article v-for="(item, key, index) in objects" :class="{ [topClass]: index === 0 }">
```

The `[ ]` brackets in the `class` binding are es2015 [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) which allow dynamically referencing a key.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/uqz1kw35/).

---

## Static Class

On the other hand, if the class name won't be dynamic, you don't need a computed at all.  You can just do:

**Array**

```
<article v-for="(item, index) in objects" :class="{ 'top-class': index === 0 }">
```

**Object** (using 3rd `v-for` argument `index`)

```
<article v-for="(item, key, index) in objects" :class="{ 'top-class': index === 0 }">
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please checkmark this answer and this will help other people as well. You can do so [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png).  Or let me know if anything is unclear.